# file getting corrupted after transfering using apache commons

Tags: html, servlets, apache-commons

i have done file uploading partially  successful .the file with extension-.html,.jpeg,.pdf etc works fine.when it comes to .zip,.rpm,.tar.gz it doesn't works.the file is getting transferred  to the desired path but the file is corrupted.

```
<tr>  
 <td>FileName</td>  
 <td><input type="text" name="filename" size="30"/></td>  
</tr> 
<tr>  
 <td>Select main category</td>  
 <td>  
  <select name="main">  
   <option >--Select--</option>  
   <option>aerospace</option>  
   <option>automotive</option>  
   <option>energy</option>  
   <option>icengines</option>  
   <option>wind</option>  
   <option>turbo</option>  
   <option>it</option>
   <option>training</option>  
  </select>  
 </td>  
</tr>  
<tr>  
    <td>Select sub category</td>
 <td>  
  <select name="sub">  
   <option >--Select--</option>  
   <option>internal</option>  
   <option>demo</option>  
   <option>best practice</option>  
   <option>marketing</option>  
   <option>papers & public</option>  
   <option>validation</option>  
   <option>training</option>  
  </select>  
 </td>  
</tr>  


<tr>  
 <td>Upload File</td>  
 <td><input type="file" name="file1"/></td>  
</tr>
```

it will get the filename along with the dropdown values and type="file",the file is transferred to the desired path but the file is corrupted for above mentioned  formats(i have checked with those formats alone).i need all the file to be stored without getting corrupted.

my servlet:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
private String filename="";     
private String main1="";  
private String location;  
private String sub;
private File uploadFile;  
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {  
try {  
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  

DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();  
ServletFileUpload fileUpload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);         
List items = fileUpload.parseRequest(request);  
Iterator ir = items.iterator();  
while(ir.hasNext()){  
FileItem item = (FileItem)ir.next();  


if(item.isFormField())
{ 

 String name = item.getFieldName();  

 if(name != null)  
 {  
 if(name.equals("userName"))
 {  
  filename = item.getString();  
 }

 else if(name.equals("main"))
 {  
  main1 = item.getString();  
 }
 else if(name.equals("sub"))
 {
     sub=item.getString();
 }
 }  
}else{  

 location = File.separator+"home"+File.separator+"adapco"+File.separator+"Desktop"+ File.separator +"output"+ File.separator +main1+File.separator+sub+File.separator+filename;
 uploadFile = new File(location);        
 long size = item.getSize();  
 if(size <= 1024*1024*1024)
 {  
  item.write(uploadFile);  
  out.println("Your File is uploaded successfully ");  
 }else{  
  out.println("Your File is not uploaded.File size should be less than 1gb");  
 }  
}  
}  
} catch (Exception e) {  
}  
}   

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that there is no exception that is swallowed by your empty catch() block? If it works with .pdf, there is no reason it does not work with other types as the protocol does not care about the content.

Comment: @ZNK:thanks for your response,instead of getting the filename with extension(eg:abc.pdf) it was saving the file with out extension(eg:abc).

Comment: and that war corrupting the file content?

Comment: ya...it was corrupting,doesn't show exact size of the file ,if a file size is of 1mb while saving it will show less than 1 mb.
"location = File.separator+"home"+File.separator+"adapco"+File.separator+"Desktop"+ File.separator +"output"+ File.separator +main1+File.separator+sub+File.separator+filename;" the "filename" will get only the name of the file and not the file itself.